# Will VFS UK Chennai call my sponsor?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I applied for my Graduation visit visa to the UK this week and I put a company sponsor letter and their bank statements as proof. 
Usually, do they make telephone calls to my sposnsor (the Company CEO) to check/verify the letters?

Comment: You shouldn't be worried unless you lied on that which is something that whether they do it or not you shouldn't lie

Comment: @nighthunter22 yes, but if you know they will call, it may be polite or even expected to notify the recipient of the call on advance

Answer (score 7):

> Will VFS UK Chennai call my sponsor?

No. The VFS is not part of the document verification team at Chennai; the VFS are external contractors who manage the collection of biometrics and provide courier services to the consulate.  VFS centres do not participate in the decision-making process.

> Usually, do they make telephone calls to my sposnsor [sic] (the Company CEO)
>   to check/verify the letters?

Assuming you mean the Visa Section at the Chennai consulate, then yes it is reasonable to expect that the document verification team will make first and second level enquiries...

[image]

...there are at the moment 42 Entry Clearance Assistants who are tasked with processing applications and a fair number of those are assigned to verification.  Their verification will be less probing if the application has been assigned to the green category...

[image]

...but based upon what you wrote (and implicit from the sheer fact that you are asking the question), your application would fall into a non-green category so you would expect a thorough document verification.

Image sources: [Chief Inspector's site](http://icinspector.independent.gov.uk/)